# Escaping hyphens in tsquery (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I need to create a tsquery based on the string of the following format:

```
something-smth-somthing-etc-etc
```

Calling `to_tsquery('something-smth-somthing-etc-etc')` returns:

```
'something-smth-somthing-etc-etc' & 'someth' & 'smth' & 'somth' & 'etc' & 'etc'
```

Clearly, the string undergoes tokenization, stemming etc. 
But in our case, the column on which we are making the FTS, already contains tsvector which consists of a single lexeme: `'something-smth-somthing-etc-etc'`.

The query
`select * from sometable where searchee @@ to_tsquery('something-smth-somthing-etc-etc')` returns no results.

How can I call `to_tsquery`, so it will not analyze the provided string and create a single lexeme query?

Or am I missing something more major here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a suming you have tsvector with mentionned value, it was not processed, but just inserted as tsvecor type:

```
t=# select to_tsvector('something-smth-somthing-etc-etc'), 'something-smth-somthing-etc-etc'::tsvector;
                                    to_tsvector                                    |             tsvector
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------
 'etc':5,6 'smth':3 'something':2 'something-smth-somthing-etc-etc':1 'somthing':4 | 'something-smth-somthing-etc-etc'
(1 row)
```

thn indeed you would have false:

```
t=# select 'something-smth-somthing-etc-etc'::tsvector @@ to_tsquery('something-smth-somthing-etc-etc');
 ?column?
----------
 f
```

to hack it you can skip processing on tsquery as well:

```
t=# select 'something-smth-somthing-etc-etc'::tsvector @@ 'something-smth-somthing-etc-etc'::tsquery;
 ?column?
----------
 t
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm